# Link component or any other element with event listener is not firing the click event if the document has active eventListener too

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, react-hooks

When attaching 'click' event listener to the DOM, elements like `Link` or some buttons with `onClick` listener that are part of the `ref` are not reacting to the `click event`. If no action is taken - it works fine, but when I call for example `toggleMenu()` it just stops there.
Something you usualy see after applying `e.stopPropagation()` or `e.preventDefault()`...

Kinda weird don't know even how to explain, better just have a look on the code.

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter, Link } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  const menuRef = useRef();

  const onDocumentClick = ({ target }) => {
    if (menuRef.current.contains(target)) {
      // event stops here if any action is taken
      // even an alert

      // comment this line to see the difference
      alert('This is not button\'s alert');
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", onDocumentClick);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", onDocumentClick);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div ref={menuRef} className="App">
        <Link to="/test">Not working</Link>
        <p>Button should show an alert saying 'clicked'</p>
        <button onClick={() => alert("clicked")}>Doesn't work</button>
      </div>

      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>

      <p>Outside of 'ref'</p>
      <Link to="/test">Works</Link>
      <p>........................</p>
      <button onClick={() => alert("clicked")}>Works</button>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

I have the code on  https://codesandbox.io/s/24z2v670wr  if you'd like to test it out.

Comment: Your both buttons for me are alerting 'clicked'. What behavior are you looking for?

Comment: @Aoradon first button isn't alerting! It does only if you comment that `alert` inside of `if`. Check the text of `alert`

Comment: This issue is happening only when there is an alert/confirm/prompt in the event listener. Right?

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings actually yeah!!! before I tested with some random method and it was failing too, but now after u asked i tried again and it works. i might did something wrong that time. anyway thank you!! do you why is it not working in case of alert?

Answer (score 1):

Solved. Should be `click` instead of `mousedown` 
details here. https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15455